# Menu button doesn't function correctly for inside pages

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my homepage http://www.hawaiidolphinswim.com/skin/tabid/92/Default.aspx When you click on the menu it expands and then when you click anywhere else on the page it hides. This is how it is intended to work across the site. However, on any other page, for example http://www.hawaiidolphinswim.com/contact.htm, when you click on the menu and then you click anywhere else on the page it doesn't hide. This is the code used to do this:

```
function navFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("nav");
  if (x.className === "nav" ){
    x.className += " active";
  } else {
    x.className = "nav";
  }
  return false;
}
$(document).on("click", function(e){
  var y = $("#nav").children();
  var z = $(".menu-btn b");
  if ($(e.target).is( y ) || $(e.target).is( z )){
    // console.log("navigation related");
  }else{
    // console.log("not navigation related");
    $(".nav").removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

How can I fix this so the menu hides on the inside pages too the same way as on the homepage?

Comment: you have some js errors on that page. try to fix them to avoid other issues.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question itself, not only on a third-party site (which will likely be fixed by the time anyone else gets to this question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you execute `getEventListeners(document)` in the chrome dev tools or any other web debugger in your problematic pages, you will see that the `click` event is not added to the page.

In other word, the click event listener is not working because your code executed before the document was ready. Your javascript code executed **before** the html dom was created so the listener couldn't be set up.

Try to put your code inside the ready block like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // Put all your js code here
});
```

That way you can make sure that the document is loaded and the event listener can be set up correctly.

Comment: Thanks Merunas Grincalaitis!

Comment: You are welcome mate. I suggest you to use plain javascript as a practice because that way you will undestand exactly what jquery is doing. I started learning jquery at the beggining too but plain js is the answer for all the problems.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get an id that doesn't exists in your page, and it gives errors and prevent the functionality of the script.

```
var video = document.getElementById("youtube"); // this id doesn't exists in the contact me page.
```

Run the `video` code inside an if statement, after checking if `video` is not null

```
if (video) {
    var source = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/50CxpeBse9Y/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&w=196&h=110&stc=true&jpg444=true&jpgq=90&sp=68&sigh=UK441E57Ci7ahRUgUu9ZjjwTRUU"; //youtube thumbnail source//
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = source;
    image.addEventListener("load", function(){
            video.appendChild(image);
        }
    );
    video.addEventListener("click", function(){
        var iframe = document.createElement( "iframe" );
        iframe.setAttribute("frameborder","0");
        iframe.setAttribute("allowfullscreen","");
        iframe.setAttribute("src","https://www.youtube.com/embed/50CxpeBse9Y?autoplay=1" );  //youtube video source//
        this.innerHTML = "";
        this.appendChild( iframe );
    });
}
```